# Porting json.dump into StringIO code to python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, stringio

I'm porting a Python 2 application to Python 3.  Currently running Python2.7 but, updating code to pass `pylint --py3k` tests, I have run into a problem with this:

```
def json_resource_file(baseurl, jsondata, resource_info):
    """
    Return a file object that reads out a JSON version of the supplied entity values data. 
    """
    response_file = StringIO()
    json.dump(jsondata, response_file, indent=2, separators=(',', ': '), sort_keys=True)
    response_file.seek(0)
    return response_file
```

It works fine with:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

but `StringIO.StringIO` doesn't exist in Python3 (according to pylint), so using:

```
from io import StringIO
```

I get an error:  "TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'" (This is running under Python 2 - I'm still preparing the ground, so to speak, and am not planning to use Python 3 until I have done as much preparation and testing as I can under Python 2.)

By way of some experimentation, I tried using `BytesIO` from `io`, but that gives a different error "TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface".

Clearly, the Python2 version of json.dump is writing `str` values to the supplied file object.  I *think* the Python3 version of json.dump also writes `str` (i.e. Unicode) values.

So my question is:  is there an easy way to dump JSON to a StringIO memory buffer that works with Python 2 and 3?

### Notes

1. I realize I could use `json.dumps` and coerce the result to whatever type `StringIO` expects, but that all seems rather heavy-handed.
2. I'm also using the following future imports as part of my porting process:

   ```
   from __future__ import (unicode_literals, absolute_import, division, print_function)
   ```
3. Currently, a solution I'm thinking of is to test the python version and import a different version of `StringIO` accordingly, but that would violate the ["Use feature detection instead of version detection"](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#use-feature-detection-instead-of-version-detection) principle.
4. In most of my code, using `from io import StringIO` appears to work fine for situations that I use `StringIO`.  It's the specific case of using a `StringIO` with `json.dump` that has caused me a few problems.

Comment: The errors occurr on python2 or python3 or on both? If the issue is with python2 then the fix is simply `try: from StringIO import StringIO except ImportError: from io import StringIO` or use `six.StringIO`

Comment: `"TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'"` was raised by Python 2, not Python 3.

Comment: Sorry, I was't clear - the errors are all under Python 2.  I haven't started actually using Python 3 yet.

Comment: @Giacomo Alzetta - Thanks!  I wondered about the import/exception approach, and maybe I'll end up doing that.  But I have a gripe that it treats the (eventually) normal case of using Python3 as an exception, which feels not-so-future-proof to me.  (E.g. suppose a new module "StringIO" comes available in the future?).  And I can't construct it the other way round because Python2 has io.StringIO.  I think using `six.StringIO` is a better option, but so far I've been able to avoid this kind of external library dependency.

Comment: Python2 will be dead soon. Port it over and fuggedaboutit.

Comment: @GrahamKlyne There aren't many alternatives. anyway `six` isn't really an issue. You can use it just in the imports. When in the future you want to drop python2 support you should be able to remove it by simply changing the imports from `from six import XXX` to `from built-package import XXX` and you are done. (Well, not in 100% of the cases but for most simple stuff it's like this).

Comment: I've just used "from six import StringIO", and all is well (under Python2), and I assume it will continue to be fine under Python3.  I would happily accept that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [six's StringIO](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.StringIO)

`from six.moves import StringIO`

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the import statement, just wrap it in a try statement:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO
```

The rest of your code should work as is, at least the code provided in your question works just fine for me.